# How to get all tr id by using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```html
<table id="tbl-orderNumber" class="ui-jqgrid-btable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class = "jqgfirstrow"></tr>
        <tr id ="AAAA"></tr>
        <tr id ="BBBB"></tr>
        <tr id ="CCCC"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have try but not work. Cannot get all id of tr AAAA, BBBB, CCCC. Thanks

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbl-orderNumber')
```

Comment: All tr's with an id? Use `tr[id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use xpath to do the all things:

```
for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="tbl-orderNumber"]//tr'):
    print(row.get_attribute('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbl-orderNumber').find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr'):
  print(row.get_attribute('id'))
```